# how to sort an element in array of hash in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

wondering how can I sort the below by say done, any idea/suggestion appreciated in advance. The below will printed in table in html format and also it would be  nice to have an arrow key next to each column on table/html format so user by clicking it  can sort the column if you got an idea for this part it also appreciated..thanks my good fellow programmers!

```
my %file_result = (
                    "name"  => "$name",
                    "total" => "$total",
                    "pass"  => "$pass",
                    "fail"  => "$fail",
                    "done"  => "$done",
                    "date"  => "$date"
                    );

            push @results, \%file_result;
       }
    }

   @results = sort {$file_result{$a->{done}} <=> $file_result{$b->{done}}}
   # @results = sort {$a->{done} <=> $a->{done}} @results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have commented out is the correct method.  Or if done is alpha, then use cmp instead of <=>

```
@results = sort {$a->{done} <=> $b->{done}} @results;
```

Comment: @user2912312 show us some sample data (only a few elements) with `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@results;`

Comment: Actually, just noticed that what you had commented out included `$a` compared with itself instead of `$a` with `$b`.  That could've been the source of your troubles as well.